# Detect that live tile is pushed from the server

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, live-tile, mpns

Is there any way to understand that the currently displayed main tile was pushed (updated) from server side?

The reason I'm asking: my app can update tile image from background agent and I want to have pushed tile image unchanged until user opened the application.

PS. I used reflector to understand tiles implementation but have not found anything I can potentially use (time stamp, any image information, no other IDs).

**EDIT**

I found out that the pushed tile image is stored as png at *Applications\Data{appguid}\Data\ShellContent* system folder. Isolated storage root folder is *Applications\Data{appguid}\Data\IsolatedStore*. So I tried to access to this folder from iso root directory using "..\ShellContent", but got Operation Not Permitted exception. The "..\IsolatedStore" works.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done anything with live tiles updated from a server (I use background agent for mine), but my suggestion would be to set a flag in IsolatedStorage during the update process, and have your background agent check for that flag.

Comment: Thanks Rich, but how I can determine the 'update process'? No events are fired when tile is pushed, I can't add any my custom logic when this happens

Comment: Ok - sorry - I'm not familiar with push updates, so I assumed that there would be an event fired, and a method run.